# Stuck in installing and using pip

Tags: python, pip

```
[root@smsc Ravi]# python get-pip.py
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
[root@smsc Ravi]#  pip install mysql-python
bash: pip: command not found
```

When I trying to install any module its showing pip not found. but when I try to install pip its showing already up to date. How to slove these problems.

Comment: Its installed, but not in your path. Did you install Python manually on this system?

Comment: If you install the latest python, it already comes with pip, but your problem seems to be that your system PATH variable does not include the python site-packages directory

Comment: Does `python -m pip install mysql-python` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check if your `pip` executable is in `/usr/local/bin` or any other path and add it to the system `PATH` variable like,

```
$ PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin # or the path where the pip is located
```

Comment: Ya its worked fine. I changed the path and working very fine

Comment: Cool. If it's working then you could accept the answer. RIght!